# How to get the values of each row in a table in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have a table that is dynamically generated and looks like this:

[image]

This is how the table is dynamically generated

```js
var cageref = CatalogueDB.ref("cageawards/" + cagecode).limitToFirst(20);
cageref.on('value', pullInventory, errData);

function pullInventory(data) {
  var container = document.getElementById('inventoryContainer')
  console.log(data.val())
  data.forEach(function(awardsSnap) {
    var awardItem = awardsSnap.val()


    // Attach an asynchronous callback to rea
    var NSNcard = `
        
                <tr>
                    <td class="serial">${awardItem.NSN}</td>
               
                    <td> ${awardItem.Nomenclature} </td>
                    <td>  <span class="serial">${awardItem.Awarddate} </td> 
                    <td> <span class="product">${awardItem.Awardid}</span> </td>
                    <td> 
                        <input type="text" placeholder="i.e. 100 EA" class="form-control" style="width: 110px;">

                     </td>
                    <td> 
                        <input type="text" placeholder="i.e. $9.23 " class="form-control" style="width: 110px;">
                    </td> 
                </tr>

                    `;
    container.innerHTML += NSNcard;
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="table-stats order-table ov-h">
  <table class="table ">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="serial">NSN</th>

        <th>Nomenclature</th>
        <th>Award Date</th>
        <th>Award #</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Price per Unit</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="inventoryContainer">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<!-- /.table-stats -->
```

what is happening is that users are shown their inventory and next to each item there is an input field for quantity and price. What I want to do now is add a SAVE button. On click of the button, I want to get the quantity and price and other values for each line item available.I'm new to javascript and I assume this is possible. How would I do that?

```
Function saveInventory(){
// Get each of the line item values


}
```

Comment: `var row = this.parentElement.parentElement` will return the `tr`. You can then use `row.querySelector()` to find specific inputs within the row.

Comment: @Barmar where would that go in the JS function

Comment: It would go in the click event listener for the Save button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the values of the table in array on click of save button, you can use something like this

```js
   

 //Run saveInventory function on Save
    document.querySelector(".btn").addEventListener("click", e => {
      saveInventory();
    });
   
    function saveInventory() {
    //Loop over th and crate column Header array
      const columnHeader = Array.prototype.map.call(
        document.querySelectorAll(".table th"),
        th => {
          return th.innerHTML;
        }
      );
    //Loop over tr elements inside table body and create the object with key being the column header and value the table data.
      const tableContent = Object.values(
        document.querySelectorAll(".table tbody tr")
      ).map(tr => {
        const tableRow = Object.values(tr.querySelectorAll("td")).reduce(
          (accum, curr, i) => {
            const obj = { ...accum };
            obj[columnHeader[i]] = curr.innerHTML;
            return obj;
          },
          {}
        );
        return tableRow;
      });
      console.log(tableContent);
    }
```

```html
 

<div class="table-stats order-table ov-h">
      <table class="table">
       <thead>
        <tr>
         <th class="serial">NSN</th>
         <th>Nomenclature</th>
         <th>Award Date</th>
         <th>Award #</th>
         <th>Quantity</th>
         <th>Price per Unit</th>
        </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody id="inventoryContainer">
        <tr>
         <td>test</td>
         <td>test</td>
         <td>test</td>
         <td>test</td>
         <td>test</td>
         <td>test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>test</td>
         <td>test</td>
         <td>test</td>
         <td>test</td>
         <td>test</td>
         <td>test</td>
        </tr>

       </tbody>

      </table><button class="btn"> Save </button>
     </div>
```

Comment: I have added comments to help you. It uses ES6 syntax to loop over row elements and create the object with all data values. Hope that helps.